# Host Socket.IO Offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, offline

Im making a private network Chat.

I need to have my server and clients not connected to the internet. but the socket io grabs the javascript from the internet when it loads the page client side.

Whats the best way to fix this? can i push the socket io javascript to the client from the server?

AKA go:
http://SERVER/socket.io-1.2.0.js

instead of:
https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js

Answer (score 1):

`socket.io` will automatically expose the client library through the HTTP/Express server it is attached to, as `/socket.io/socket.io.js` (so the full URL in your case would be `http://SERVER/socket.io/socket.io.js`)